# How should i throw exception error from stored procedure such as " String or binary data would be truncated. "?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2012. Based on the stored procedure variable length; input value is automatically trimmed and inserted to the table.

Example : I am passing a variable `@name varchar(10)`:

```
@name VARCHAR(10) = null
```

However, on inserting the record which is more than 10 characters through stored procedure, record get inserted by trimming the characters to first 10 digit.

I am expecting to get the error exception such as

> String or binary data would be truncated

How should I throw an exception error from the stored procedure?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_test 
(
    [ID] INT,
    [NAME] VARCHAR(10),
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_test
    (@name VARCHAR(10) = NULL)
AS
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_test 
    VALUES (1, @name)

    INSERT INTO tbl_test([ID], [NAME]) 
    VALUES (2, @name)
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior depends on the [`ANSI_WARNINGS` session setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql).

With `ANSI_WARNINGS ON` (the default in modern Microsoft SQL Server APIs), you will get the expected "string or binary data would be truncated" error when data are inserted into a column with a shorter length. `ANSI_WARNINGS ON` is implicitly set by `ANSI_DEFAULTS ON`.

With `ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`, the data will be silently truncated.

However, when you pass a parameter value that is longer than the defined parameter length, the value is truncated without error or warning regardless of the session setting. This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) that may not be what one expects:

> SET ANSI_WARNINGS is not honored when passing parameters in a
>   procedure, user-defined function, or when declaring and setting
>   variables in a batch statement. For example, if a variable is defined
>   as char(3), and then set to a value larger than three characters, the
>   data is truncated to the defined size and the INSERT or UPDATE
>   statement succeeds.

so it is important to ensure supplied values do not exceed the defined parameter length.

Comment: thank you. I added the syntax for testing. However, i wasnt able to recreate the error

Comment: @goofyui, how are you testing exactly? Run `DBCC USEROPTIONS` to verify the sessions settings.

Comment: i received :  SET Options =  ansi_warnings;  Value = SET

Comment: @goofyui, I updated my answer. I thought you were referring to the insert rather than the stored procedure call.

Comment: Expected result over here is to throw the exception. Stored Procedure should not trim the characters by itself. Either we accept the whole value (or)  should not accept. How should we do that?

Comment: SQL Server will not do that for you. I added the documentation link to my answer. You'll need the validate that the supplied value does not exceed the defined parameter length and raise an error yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this to work is to make sure your parameters are longer than the table column. Doesn't have to be much longer - one character would be enough. Then if you get passed a longer string, it will still be longer inside the stored procedure.

At that point you can either test for the length being too long and raise your own error, or if you try and put it in the table you'll get an error anyway. Either way, at least you'll know.

Comment: By the way, if you do this, make sure you document why, or some future Dev will come along and "fix" it for you.

Comment: Thank you ..! That was a great advice ..! But, we get this errors in SQL 2008. Is something got changed in SQL 2012 or the versions higher than that ?

Comment: Actually, when the stored silently trim the characters .. gives us invalid data in the back end. It should have thrown error. Anyways, i will handle the error exception per your advice